# unable to print console.log in button react-native

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6

i have created a custom button component for reuseability here is my button code

```
export default function AppButton({ title, color = "", marginVertical = 0 }) {
  return (
    <TouchableHighlight
      style={[
        styles.button,
        { backgroundColor: colors[color], marginVertical: marginVertical }]}
    >
    <Text style={styles.text}>{title}</Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  );
}
```

here is my button in which I want to print console .log

```
<AppButton
       title="login"
       onPress={() => console.log("email and password recieved")}
/>
```

[image]

Comment: Why did you wrote the onPress like 'onPres[![enter image description here][1]][1]s' this? And another thing is you are not receiving this props on AppButton component I think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, you need to pass the onpress function as props to touchable highlight.

```
export default function AppButton({ title, color = "", marginVertical = 0 }) {
  return (
    <TouchableHighlight
      onPress={onClick}
      style={[
        styles.button,
        { backgroundColor: colors[color], marginVertical: marginVertical },
      ]}
    >
      <Text style={styles.text}>{title}</Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  );
}
```

```
 <AppButton
        title="login"
        onClick={() => console.log("email and password recieved")}
      />
```

More details can be found in the docs: https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchablehighlight

Comment: thank you Roy Chan its working when I pass in touchable ,and in parameter